# Visual Studio 2010 Pro, Class diagram elements keep moving

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a class diagram in my project. The elements keep moving around between saves. This is purely an aesthetic problem. Is this by design, or is there a setting somewhere to say leave the lines where I put them?

In case that isn't clear, you can  move the connecting lines around, and interface lollipops. The layout engine doesn't mind putting interface lollipop's text over the top of inheritance lines. I do. So I move the lollipops, or the inheritance lines, but when I reopen the diagram it has moved them again.

Comment: I'd also like to know - this is not the only annoyance like this that VC does on saves.

Comment: I'm delighted it's not just me, and a little miffed there isn't a solution. I'll try and raise it as a bug with MS I guess :)

Comment: I too would like it if this was addressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've logged it with Microsoft as a possible bug:

[Visual Studio diagram editor bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/635680/vs-2010-pro-diagram-editor-doesnt-save-element-positions-lines-and-lollipops)

Fingers crossed :)